# Can I programmately set the referer header of a request?

Tags: http-referer

Is there any way, using javascript on a page or in any other way, to forward a user to another page or just make him make a GET request, but the HTTP request he sends to the target page to have a custom referer header?

For example can i do something like

request.setRequestHeader("Referer", "http://www.google.com");

?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this using Javascript.

The modern browsers will not allow you to fake the Referer header.

Comment: Do you think you could add any references/links for this?

Answer (score 0):

make

```
wget --header='Referer: http://yourtestreferer.com/' http://target.com
```